# Cambiar el icono de mi aplicacion en flutter

Tags: flutter

tengo este codigo en mi pubspect.yaml para modificar el icono de mi aplicacion, pero no funciona, no puedo cambiar el icono de mi aplicacion, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.2
  slimy_card: ^1.0.4
  provider: ^6.0.5
  #flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "aa/Icono_edese.ico"
```

Comment: La pregunta no está bien planteada. Recuerda dar detalles concretos de qué estás haciendo y cómo lo haces. No indicas si usas un package externo, que se tiene que presuponer por el hecho de que muestras tu archivo pubspec, tampoco indicas cual es el package ni qué parte del código te falla. Ni qué cómo estás modificando los iconos. Recuerda tomarte más de 10 segundos para hacer una pregunta, obtendrás mejores respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El paquete que estas usando flutter_launcher_icons nos sirve para generar los diferentes tamaños que necesitamos ya automatizado para las diferentes plataformas en las que se necesita, para esto se define la versión que vamos estar utilizando, así como le definimos los parámetros que son requeridos recomendando que en Android sea launcher_icon, según la [documentacion](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) en pub.dev del paquete como también es recomendable añadir adaptive_icon_background para una mejor implementación.

Te recomiendo esta configuración:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0 // Ultima version

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "direccion de tu imagen"
  adaptive_icon_background: "direccion de tu imagen"
```

siendo image_path y adaptive_icon_background la misma imagen o no si así lo requiere, tambien asegúrate que la dirección este bien escrita